# Wrapping text in HTML/CSS: How to put a preformatted text on the right side instead of under?

Tags: html, css

programmers! I am workin on coding an infinate limousine and cant figure it out how do you place the preformatted text (pre) on the left side instead of under in the div "wrapper".

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 30vh;
  padding-left: 25vw;
  width: 271px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
                             _________
                            /        |
                          /          |
      __________________/()__________|
    {}_________________|___________=_|
   { }      ______     |           . |
 _{ #}_    /##  ##\    |             |
{______)__|##    ##|___|_____________|
            ##__##  \
</pre>
  <pre class="seat">
_____________________________________________________
                                                    |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
__________________________________________________=_|
                                                  . |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
</pre>
</div>
```

I have tried `fload:right;` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Basic_concepts_of_grid_layout) is the way to go when it comes to column-based interfaces:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  /* Make two columns of equal width */
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}


/* Original styles */

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
                             _________
                            /        |
                          /          |
      __________________/()__________|
    {}_________________|___________=_|
   { }      ______     |           . |
 _{ #}_    /##  ##\    |             |
{______)__|##    ##|___|_____________|
            ##__##  \
</pre>
  <pre class="seat">
_____________________________________________________
                                                    |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
__________________________________________________=_|
                                                  . |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by giving the ".wrapper" class a `display: flex;` property and setting the padding and margin to your preference.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 30vh;
  padding-left: 25vw;
  width: 271px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
                             _________
                            /        |
                          /          |
      __________________/()__________|
    {}_________________|___________=_|
   { }      ______     |           . |
 _{ #}_    /##  ##\    |             |
{______)__|##    ##|___|_____________|
            ##__##  \
</pre>
  <pre class="seat">
_____________________________________________________
                                                    |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
__________________________________________________=_|
                                                  . |
                                                    |
____________________________________________________|
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @inSync for solving the problem. I appreciate it!